# Rewrite files or directories back to root

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite anything that comes after `example.tld` back to the root directory if the file or directory does not exist. Say the user went to `example.tld/index.php` or `example.tld/ex/ex.html`, and there was nothing there, how would I redirect them back to the root? I am new to htaccess because I've never had to use it before now.

Comment: This has been answered millions of times before. Did you even bother to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ErrorDocument` but it will only fire a 404 error (page not found **but** no redirect).

If you want to redirect every non-existing file/folder to root (home page) then put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

This code will redirect to home page.

Note: make sure to enable **mod_rewrite**

Comment: Well, actually is looks like it's just not working. I have rewrite enabled, and this in the root directory.

Comment: `RewriteRule: invalid HTTP response code for flag 'R'` I went to an htaccess tester an got this.